# Flutter Push Notification image not showing on all devices

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, notifications, android-icons

I am using the 'flutter_local_notification' plugin. When I installed the app on one phone, the push notification default icon is being shown properly but when I installed the app on another android phone, the notification image is not shown instead a grey circle is shown in its place while the text and big image are shown properly.

I am using a png image present in 'mipmap' dir in the res folder.
Kindly help me to resolve this issue:)

[image]

Comment: Notification icons should have a transparent background.

Comment: @DarShan I am using png format icons with the transparent background still the icon is displaying on one android phone and not displaying on another android phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successfully solved this bottleneck by making my icon white in color with transparent background